# $first in ng-repeat with an ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
<li ng-repeat"item in items" ng-if="item.type && item.type=='image'">
 <span ng-class="{'selected':$first}">{{item.title}}</span>
</li>
```

What I'm trying to do is display all item Titles only if it's of type image, and have the first item have the class `selected`.

The issue comes with the `ng-if`. If the first item is not of type image, then the actual first item shown does not have the `selected` class.

How do I update this?

Comment: `item in item`? don't confuse yourself and Angular with that.. list name should be plural ideally

Comment: filter the collection before iterating on it. Using a filter, or in your component. `item in items | filter:{type: 'image'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new list that only has images. Then `ng-repeat` over that:

```
$scope.onlyImages = $scope.items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.type && item.type === 'image';
});

<li ng-repeat"item in onlyImages">
   <span ng-class="{'selected':$first}">{{item.title}}</span>
</li>
```

You could also do this in the template with a filter, but it would be more expensive since it runs on each digest cycle.

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks. Just wondering, would it be expensive to do it this way though if I have one big collection that I'm using for a bunch of views? (i.e. type:image; type:video; type:text, etc.)

Comment: Expensive in terms of performance? Or memory? If your list is huge it may take some time to filter, but at least we're only doing it once. In terms of memory, we're creating a new list with only the images, but we're not actually duplicating the images. We're only duplicating the references.

Comment: That will be **more** efficient than filtering with ng-if from the view.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks guys. I just wanted to confirm!